# Mysql - Concat fields based on value of field

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Given a table like this:

```
id     name     field
1      walt       a
2      hurley     b
3      jack       c
4      kate       a
5      sawyer     a
6      john       a
7      ben        b
8      miles      null
9      juliet     c
10     jacob      d
11     richard    null
```

How would you transfer it into this:

```
id     ids       names                      field
1      1,4,5,6   walt, kate, sawyer, john     a
2      2,7       hurley, ben                  b
3      8         miles                       null
4      3,9       jack, juliet                  c
5      10        jacob                        d
6      11        richard                     null
```

It needs to look at all the rows having the same field value. Then it needs to "merge" all other values based on equality of the field value. However if the field value is null, it should do nothing.

Comment: I would handle display issues in application code .

Comment: thought about that, but curious then, would you ever use mysql group_concat?

Comment: (almost) never.

Comment: so, when would you? :) is this some general known "best practice advice" to keep selects simple and do data arranging via application code? maybe some good literature on that?

Comment: I might use it in combination with some other aggregation, and/or for certain kinds of ranking queries. I don't think I'm qualified to comment on best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work:

```
mysql> set @x:= 1;

mysql> select group_concat(id) as ids, group_concat(name) as names, field 
from `a table like this` group by coalesce(field, @x:=@x+1);
+---------+-----------------------+-------+
| ids     | names                 | field |
+---------+-----------------------+-------+
| 8       | miles                 | NULL  |
| 11      | richard               | NULL  |
| 1,4,5,6 | walt,kate,sawyer,john | a     |
| 2,7     | hurley,ben            | b     |
| 3,9     | jack,juliet           | c     |
| 10      | jacob                 | d     |
+---------+-----------------------+-------+
```

Basically, I tricked the query into treating each NULL as a non-NULL value that increments each time we evaluate it, so each row with a NULL counts as a distinct group.

---

Re your comment:

You can also initialize a variable within the query like this:

```
select group_concat(id) as ids, group_concat(name) as names, field 
from (select @x:=1) AS _init
cross join `a table like this` 
group by coalesce(field, @x:=@x+1);
```

Comment: Nice trick indeed! However unfortunately in my query I wont be able to set a @x variable like this.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. However something weird is happening. Sometimes when I run the query, the field value is NULL where it should have a value - e.g. the row with the names “hurley,ben” suddenly have a field value of NULL instead of "b". This only happens sometimes. So maybe it is some kind of race condition where @x does not increment fast enough? Will have to look into it... my real life table is a bit larger.

Comment: @Hans are some of your `field` values numeric? It could be that `@x` ends up matching with some at random; you could try initializing `@x` to a value high (or low) enough, that you can guarantee now collisions with real values. _(Another possibility is that there could be something weird happening with type coercion in the `coalesce` due to `field` being a string and @x being a number.)_

Comment: the field values are indeed numeric. counting down (@x:=@x-1) instead up fixed the issue. many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

GROUP_CONCAT can be used to aggregate data from different rows into a concatenated string (as its name would suggest); it also supports and ORDER BY clause of it's own, so you want make doubly sure corresponding values end up in the same relative position of the list*.

```
SELECT MIN(id)
   , GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id)
   , GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY id)
   , field
FROM theTable
WHERE field IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY field
UNION 
SELECT id, id, name, field
FROM theTable
WHERE field IS NULL
;
```

** aggregate functions ignore NULL values, so technically if either id or name contain NULL, the lists will become misaligned; this could be remedied with something like `GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(concatenated_value, '[null]') ORDER BY ordering_value)`*